# Check the integral of complex function, verification. Cauchy integral formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have to compute the following integral:
$$\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{2^z}{(3z+5)^7}$$

I see immediately that I need to use the Cauchy integral formula. I rewrite the integral as follows:

$$\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{2^z}{(3z+5)^7} = \oint_{|z|=2}\frac{(1/3)^72^z}{(z+5/3)^7}$$

Now I can use the Cauchy integral formula, since $\frac{5}{3}$ is in the contour. I used the Cauchy integral formula for derivatives, and found:

$$\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{(1/3)^72^z}{(z+5/3)^7} = \frac{2\pi i \cdot (1/3)^7 \cdot 2^{(5/3)} \cdot \log^6(2)}{6!} $$

Am I right, or did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost. It's $-\dfrac53$ that matters here, not $\dfrac53$, and therefore you have\begin{align}\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{2^z}{(3z+5)^7} &= \frac{2\pi i\left(1/3\right)^72^{-5/3} \log^6(2)}{6}\\&=\frac{2\pi i\log^6(2)}{2^{5/3}3^76!}.\end{align}